Is there a way of adding a 'social share' button to a post 'loop' on the archive page so that the URL shared is that of the post and not the archive?
I created a post loop to display all my posts on the archive page and I want to add a social share buttoin to these loops so that a user can share the article from the archive page without having to open the post and then share it.
I tried adding a social shar ebutton directly in the loop thinking that it would pull the post URL but it doesn;t

For this I suggest you to install AddToAny Share Buttons plugin which Provides customizable share buttons for various social networks. Once this is installed and activated we can use ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT function in our loop to show social share icons.
You can use the given code to show posts with soical share icons in loop.
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> >
            <header class="entry-header" >
                <h2 class="entry-title" >
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </h2>
            </header>
            <!-- .entry-header -->
            
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- .entry-content -->

            <footer class="entry-footer">
                <div class="social-share-buttons">
                    <?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) {
                        ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT( array(
                            'buttons' => array(
                                'facebook', 'twitter', 'linkedin', 'pinterest', 'email', 'share_more'
                            ),
                            'button_style' => 'icon',
                            'title' => get_the_title(),
                            'linkname' => get_the_permalink(),
                        ) );
                    } ?>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!-- .entry-footer -->
        </article>
        <!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    
    <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
    
<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'No posts found' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

